# Is it possible to run queries in parallel in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I wanted to do an insert and update at the same time in Redshift. For this I am inserting the data into a temporary table, removing the updated entries from the original table and inserting all the new and updated entries. Since Redshift uses concurrency, sometimes entries are duplicated, because the delete started before the insert was finished. Using a very large sleep for each operation this does not happen, however the script is very slow. Is it possible to run queries in parallel in Redshift?

Hope someone can help me , thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on MVCC (multi-version coherency control) and transactions.  Redshift can only only run one query at a time (for a session) but that is not the issue.  You want to COMMIT both changes at the same time (COMMIT is the action that causes changes to be apparent to others).  You do this by wrapping your SQL statement in a transaction (BEGIN ... COMMIT) and executed in the same session (not clear if you are using multiple sessions).  All changes made within the transaction will only be visible to the session making the changes UNTIL COMMIT when ALL the changes made by the transaction will be visible to everyone at the same moment.

A few things to watch out for - if your connection is in AUTOCOMMIT mode then you may break out of your transaction early and COMMIT partial results.  Also when you are working in transactions your source table information is unchanging (so you see consistent data during your transaction) and this information isn't allowed to change for you.  This means that if you have multiple sessions changing table data you need to be careful about the order in which they COMMIT so the right version of data is presented to each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin transaction;

<run the queries in parallel>

end transaction;
```

In this specific case do this:

```
create temp table stage (like target); 

insert into stage 
select * from source 
where source.filter = 'filter_expression'; 

begin transaction;

delete from target 
using stage 
where target.primarykey = stage.primarykey; 
insert into target 
select * from stage;

end transaction;

drop table stage;
```

See:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html